Zeta Hurwitz function bounds of summation
I have been trying to derive the following equality
$$
\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=0}^{p-1} \frac{1}{n^s}\left[\cos \left(2 \pi \frac{m q}{p}\left(q^*-1+n\right)\right)+\cos \left(2 \pi \frac{m q}{p}\left(q^*-1-n\right)\right)\right] = \frac{p^{1-s}}{2}\left[\zeta\left(s,-\frac{q^*-1}{p}\right)+\zeta\left(s, \frac{q^*-1}{p}\right)-\left(\frac{p}{1-q^*}\right)^s\right],\quad \mathrm{(*)}$$
where
$$
\zeta(s, a)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+a)^s},
$$
is the zeta Hurwitz function and $q,p$ are relatively prime integers with $q\neq \pm1~\mathrm{mod}~p$, $p\neq0$ and $q^* = q^{-1} ~\mathrm{mod}~p$ (although, these conditions should not be relevant to the derivation in my opinion).
So far I have tried mapping $n\mapsto pn +1-q^*$ for the first cos and similarly $n\mapsto pn -1 +q^*$ for the second in order to make the cos become one for all values of $n$ and $m$. This mapping leaves me with something that looks like two zeta Hurwitz functions but the bounds of summation have changed. The equation is now (after factoring out $s$ powers of $p$ from the denominator and one from the sum over $m$)
$$
\frac{p^{1-s}}{2} \left[\sum_{n=q^*/p}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\left(n+\frac{1-q^*}{p}\right)^s}+ \sum_{n=(2-q^*)/p}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\left(n-\frac{1-q^*}{p}\right)^s}\right].
$$
I believe that we are now summing in increments of $\frac{1}{p}$. This resembles ($\mathrm{*}$) but I have not been able to finish the derivation.
